# XNextEvent Doesn't works for some reason

Tags: c++, xlib

I'm trying to catch keypress events using XLib. But for some reasons XNextEvent not working.
I'm not receiving any errors, but it looks like my program stuck on the line of "XNextEvent" call.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    XEvent event;
    KeySym key;
    char text[255];
    Display *dis;

    dis = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    while (1) {
        XNextEvent(dis, &event);
        if (event.type==KeyPress && XLookupString(&event.xkey,text,255,&key,0) == 1) {
            if (text[0]=='q') {
                XCloseDisplay(dis);
                return 0;
            }
            printf("You pressed the %c key!\n", text[0]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is **never** a good diagnoses. What's happening ? Is there an error message ? Or an unexpected result ? Please **edit** your question to precise How it doesn't work.

Comment: @hivert It is obvious what the problem is. No need of an edit

Comment: Maybe but I think explaining SO newcomers how to ask good question is important.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how X11 windowing system works.

Read [this](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/keyboard-pointer/keyboard-pointer.html) carefully. The key point is :

> The source of the event is the viewable window that the pointer is in.

You do not create a window, therefore your program doesn't receive keyboard events. Even if you created window, it has to have focus :

> The window used by the X server to report these events depends on the window's position in the window hierarchy and whether any intervening window prohibits the generation of these events.

Comment: I need to catch keyboard events globally so It doesn't matter which window is currently active. Is that possible with xlib or I should use another lib? Thanks!

Comment: @Alexweb not sure if it is possible with xlib

Answer (score 1):

**Working example**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    XEvent event;
    Display *dis;
    Window root;
    Bool owner_events = False;
    unsigned int modifiers = ControlMask | LockMask;


    dis = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    root = XDefaultRootWindow(dis);
    unsigned int keycode = XKeysymToKeycode(dis, XK_P);
    XSelectInput(dis,root, KeyPressMask);
    XGrabKey(dis, keycode, modifiers, root, owner_events, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync);

    while (1) {
        Bool QuiteCycle = False;
        XNextEvent(dis, &event);
        if (event.type == KeyPress) {
            cout << "Hot key pressed!" << endl;
            XUngrabKey(dis, keycode, modifiers, root);
            QuiteCycle = True;
        }
        if (QuiteCycle) {
            break;
        }
    }
    XCloseDisplay(dis);
    return 0;
}
```